# eJabberd: Retrive Chat Room history

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I know it is very old question but I need some help regarding this urgently.

As per [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/909825/ejabberd-room-history-is-erased-after-server-restart) thread, The chat room history only stored in RAM and it will removed if we restart the ejabberd service.

Is it possible to retrieve the removed history from DB (I am using MySQL) and restore it to RAM as what it was before restarting the server?

Thanks for the understanding.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to retrieve the removed history from DB (I am using MySQL) and restore it to RAM as what it was before restarting the server?

No, there is no option to store recent room message history in a persistent database.

You can enable mod_mam and configure rooms to use MAM archiving. That stores all the room messages, not only the last X messages. The problem is that those are archived, but not sent automatically to new occupants.